# What fantasy book has love change a sorcerer’s mind about destroying something?

Tags: story-identification

I read it in the 1970s. I don't remember the title but the story goes something like this...

A sorcerer gets angry with something (or place) and goes about setting in motion a spell to destroy it.

I think that most of the book is spent in finding what he needs for the spell.

Along the way he meets a woman, and they fall in love.  Through their love, the sorcerer decides not to destroy the place he wanted to, but the spell is already in motion. In order to stop it he must die in the process, which he does.

The woman survives to grow into an old wise woman. The end of the book shows the lovers reincarnated as children.

I know it sounds a bit like ‘Tigana’ by Guy Gavriel Kay, but it isn’t that book.

Comment: Are you sure it was the 1970s? It sounds somewhat like _Tigana_ by Guy Gavriel Kay, published in 1990.

Comment: I have to agree with mike here it does remind me of tigana as well doesn't mean guy didn't have influence from an older book he may have read.

Comment: Thanks but Tigana is not the book

Comment: It is remotely possible that it is "The Power that Preserves" by Stephen R Donaldson http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_that_Preserves

But this book doesn't quite match your description.

Comment: Definitely NOT "The Power that Preserves", which I have read.

Comment: I was reminded of "The Time Master," a fantasy trilogy by Louise Cooper which I read way back in the day, but I don't think it ended with Tarod (the arrogant, incredibly powerful sorcerer) and Cyllan (his beloved) getting *reincarnated* to try again. On the other hand, I just now learned that "The Time Master" was an expanded rewrite of the plot of a single novel called *Lord of No Time,* which I've never read.